# communication between grandparentVC and rootVC

Tags: objective-c

My project is like this: **rootVC**(map) -> **childVC**(sidebar) -> **grandchildVC**(tableview)

I want to send data from **grandchildVC** -> **rootVC** but with a delegate it doesn't work.

if I transport the data via delegates like this: **grandchildVC** -> **childVC** -> **rootVC** it works...

but this cannot be the solution, it seems really dirty...

so..
1) can somebody help me to understand why i cant communicate directly?

2) are there some better solutions to send data from the **grandchildVC** to **rootVC**?

Comment: you can communicate directly can we see some code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't tell use what messages you are trying to send, but notifications (NSNotification) may be the solution you are looking for. The grandchild can post notifications without caring who is listening, or even how many.

Comment: i'm passing an array with objects to define and set annotations on my root(map)

Comment: i tried it with the notification and it works fine. thank you

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the rootVC is the delegate of the child and implements the delegate protocol.